# Search box is not friendly with dark OS themes

Tags: feature-request, design

The search box in the top right of the sites has a white background explicitly declared. If you are using a dark theme for your OS, the default text colour is often white or near white, making it appear as if the search box is not working. Could you fix this?

Possible fix:

Add a `color:black` declaration for the CSS of `#hsearch .textbox`.

Also: The Tags box tends to flash white while loading the suggestions.

PICTURES:

[image: Text in, but not shown]

Highlighted (this would look the same if color:black was applied aswell):

[image: Here]

EDIT: The box to type in your openID while logging in is also affected.

Comment: Pictures added. There isn't much to see.

Comment: Heh... So it's letting the system text color come through, but overriding the background color? Oops...

Comment: @Shog9: Yes. It's not alone in this at least. Pidgin does the opposite (overrides the text color, and allows the background through).

Comment: This problem was among the many reasons I de-themed my browser when I was running a dark theme.

Comment: I have the opposite situation: black text on black background. But I have a different suggestion. Instead of setting the colours, just don't set them to anything. This works well with the default settings, but if you set only one, then, obviously, it doesn't. At the very least it could be made an option in account settings... not a huge thing to ask, I suppose.

Comment: @wvxvw Confirming this - have same problem.